# No Initialization Functions in MySQL Library

Tags: mysql, linker-errors, libraries, mysql-connector

I have downloaded the [MySQL Connector/C driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) from the official website, the version that I believe is supposed to be released next to 5.6.

I then obviously wanted to use the library so I wrote a small application. During linkage, I however got a strange linker errors saying it cannot find the functions `mysql_library_init()` and `mysql_library_end()`.

When I use a command to check for the functions inside the library, `nm /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a > ~/Desktop/symbols`, I indeed cannot find the functions the linker mentioned.

The functions I do find however are `mysql_server_init` and `mysql_server_end`, which are [according to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-server-init.html), marked as deprecated. (There are more functions in there too)

What am I doing wrong? I am using version 6.1.2 of the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that the documentation is ahead of the code.

I am a DBA, not a C programmer, though I dabble in server internals.  If the file `include/mysql.h` in the MySQL Server source files is any indication, the `mysql_server_*` functions are the ones you're looking for.

```
/*
  mysql_server_init/end need to be called when using libmysqld or
  libmysqlclient (exactly, mysql_server_init() is called by mysql_init() so
  you don't need to call it explicitely; but you need to call
  mysql_server_end() to free memory). The names are a bit misleading
  (mysql_SERVER* to be used when using libmysqlCLIENT). So we add more general
  names which suit well whether you're using libmysqld or libmysqlclient. We
  intend to promote these aliases over the mysql_server* ones.
*/
#define mysql_library_init mysql_server_init
#define mysql_library_end mysql_server_end
```

*"We intend to promote these aliases over the mysql_server* ones."*

They promoted them in the documentation, apparently.

It looks like [Bug #65887](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65887) was a report of the same problem, that they never really got around to doing anything with.

You might also find [MariaDB's implementation](https://downloads.mariadb.org/client-native/) of the C API "for MariaDB and MySQL" to be a viable and perhaps more agreeably-licensed alternative.

Comment: Oh I see, the problem was I am not programming in C so I didn't get the header macros. Thanks a lot! :D